# Scroll Overflow into a hidden one

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overflow

I have a scroll overflow into a hidden one

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/50g4qoxz/)

The problem is that the page won't scroll so I can see the rest of content, notice that i want the sidebar and the top bar to stay fixed in their place, only the body with the gray color to scroll

```
html,body{
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-    color: #e5e2e6; color:#000000; padding-top: 20px; overflow:scroll;">
                test1<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                test2<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                test3<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                test4<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                test5<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                test6<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            </div>
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but you don't need to define col-xs-9 col-sm-9 etc. These styles will cascade up, so col-xs-9 essentially means use 9 of the 12 grid positions for all sizes xs and up. If you want different behavior at larger sizes you can also define those, eg. col-m-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you want ? 
[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50g4qoxz/8/)

Remove `overflow: hidden;` from `html, body` and then update HTML code like this :

HTML code updated :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: #e5e2e6;" >
    <div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%;">
        <div class="row" style="height:100%;" align="center">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 sidebar" style="height:100%; position: fixed; z-index: 10;">
                <p class="title" style="text-align:center; color:#FFFFFF; font-size:2.6vw;">TITLE</p>
    </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9" style="background-color: #3a3633; color:white; z-index: 10; margin-left: 25%; position: fixed; ">
                <span class="label label-default pull-left" style="font-size:15px; margin:1%;">TEST</span>
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color: #e5e2e6; color:#000000; padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 25%; ">
                        test1<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                        test2<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                        test3<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                        test4<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                        test5<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                        test6<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I've added `position: fixed;` to elements you wanted fixed and add some padding to show content properly

I've changed the grey content :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color: #e5e2e6; color:#000000; padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 25%; ">
```

`padding-left: 25%;` because of the width of the left bar

`padding-top: 30px;` because of the height of the top bar

The top bar  :

```
<div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9" style="background-color: #3a3633; color:white; z-index: 10; margin-left: 25%; position: fixed; ">
```

`margin-left: 25%;` is the width of the left bar

The left sidebar :
      `<div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 sidebar" style="height:100%; position: fixed; z-index: 10;">`

The `z-index` with `position: fixed;` is used to put on first plan the two fixed bars

FYI

Its not needed to include all of the `col-xs` `col-sm` `col-md` and `col-lg` if you are going to use same size for the column. e.g. including only `col-xs-3` will work for all `col-xs-3` `col-sm-3` `col-md-3` and `col-lg-3`. And `col-sm-9` will work for `col-xs-9` `col-sm-9` `col-md-9` and `col-lg-9`

Comment: can you explain to me what you did please ?

Comment: i dont know why , but when i implement your solution on my page , it doesnt worl

Comment: I've edited my post with explanations. By the way, don't use inline style with bootstrap columns. I think it's better to separate grid systems and specific css, like for example <div class="col-xs-3"><div class="specificStyle"></div></div> and then style it with a CSS file

Comment: yes i will thank you , but it doesnt work and i dont know why

Comment: What does not work ? Can you update the fiddle with the exact same code that don't work and i can help you with

Answer (score 0):

You could try using bootstraps built in tools to handle this type of thing. Use class navbar-fixed-top for your top bar, and sidebar-nav for your sidepanel.